# Subsetting the data

Tags: python, dataframe, subset

I have dataframe with 3 columns as shown here:

| ID | Date | Page |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 1 | C |
| 1 | 1 | B |
| 2 | 1 | B |
| 2 | 2 | C |
| 2 | 2 | A |

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
'Date' : [1,1,1,1,2,2],
'Page' : ['A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A']
       }
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I want customers(`ID`) who have visited page `B` from page `A` by ignoring other pages and dates. Like in the given data `ID` 2 visited from page `B` to page `A`(ignore any other page in between.)

Expected output:

```py
ID 
2.
```

Comment: Can you please what is your expected? please avoid image. It does not reach wider audience. you can edit and post it

Comment: I've added your question with the code you need to represent df in python. Please follow @yogi suggestion and edit the question with the output you need written in python, this will also help you learning. ciao!

Comment: Welcome! please clarify ID is the customer column? It will be great if you add the desired output dataframe.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions and edit. Please do let me know if it is understandable.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, I think it will help you to implement as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
'ID': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
'Date' : [1,1,1,1,2,2],
'Page' : ['A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# remove all records that not A or B
df = df[df['Page'].isin(['A', 'B'])]

# sort the values by ID at first and then by Date
df.sort_values(["ID", "Date"]) 

# create new dataframe with the A and B order 
concat_df = df.groupby(["ID"])['Page'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

# filter the cases that B visited first
print(concat_df[concat_df['Page'] == "B,A"])
```